# How to create a Linux executable which builds, run tests and run a python script?

Tags: python, unit-testing

How to convert a python script to Linux executable which should build, run tests and run the program.

Comment: If you want an *executable* for Linux: `bash`, If you want a *binary*, Python is not the good choice

Comment: Use PyInstaller to generate a single executable file from python script, reference: http://www.pyinstaller.org/

Comment: How do you create an executable that first run the tests then build the code and run the program. I am new to this. Any samples?